# how to add code to change the <h2> to red when the convert button is clicked

Tags: javascript

Here is my code so far:

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>

<TITLE>Celsius to Fahrenheit Converter</TITLE>

</HEAD>

<script>

function convert(){

var celsius =document.getElementById("celsius").value

var fahrenheit;

if(celsius != ''){

fahrenheit = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32;

document.getElementById("fahrenheit").value =Math.round( fahrenheit);

}else{

alert("Please enter a value!");

}


document.getElementById("h2").style.color = "red";


}

</script>

<BODY>

<FORM NAME="test">

<H2><font color="blue">Celsius to Fahrenheit Converter</font></H2>

<P>Enter temp in celsius: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" id="celsius"><BR><BR>

<P>Temp in fahrenheit: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" id="fahrenheit"><BR><BR>

<INPUT TYPE="Button" Value="Convert" onClick="convert()">

</P>

</FORM>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: write the code inside a container provided by stackoverflow.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Celsius to Fahrenheit Converter</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<script>

function convert(){

var celsius =document.getElementById("celsius").value;
var fahrenheit;

if(celsius != ''){ 
 fahrenheit = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
 document.getElementById("fahrenheit").value =Math.round( fahrenheit);
}
else{
 alert("Please enter a value!");
}

document.getElementById("fontId").style.color = "red";   
}

</script>

<BODY>
<FORM NAME="test">
<H2 ><font id="fontId" color="blue">Celsius to Fahrenheit Converter</font></H2>

<P>Enter temp in celsius: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" id="celsius"><BR><BR>
<P>Temp in fahrenheit: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" id="fahrenheit"><BR><BR>
<INPUT TYPE="Button" Value="Convert" onClick="convert()">
</P>
</FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```